# What term denotes a Japanese style living room?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

I searched the word 居間 on Jisho and noticed that it referred to a Western style living room. I originally assumed that リビングルーム referred to a Western style living room. Is there a term for a Japanese style living room?

Comment: I guess 和室 is what you're looking for.

Comment: Is it really true that it can't refer to a Japanese style room? I don't see anything in its definition to suggest that.

Comment: 和室is a Japanese room.

Comment: 和室 isn't necessarily a living room though.

Comment: Yes, a Japanese room has tatami mats.

Comment: FWIW, the Japanese *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* uses 居間 for the Dursleys' (presumably western) living room.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「居間{いま}」 can be used regardless of the styles you speak of.  (You should not trust everything Jisho tells you.)

Another highly common word is 「（お）茶{ちゃ}の間{ま}」.

I should perhaps mention the fact that rooms in Japanese homes have traditionally been far more multipurpose than their "Western" counterparts.  Items such as futon and folding low tables make that possible.  A room that is used as an 居間 or お茶の間 during the day can easily turn into a "bedroom" at night.  That transformation would not even take five minutes.